# Tomcat shutdown leading to data loss from executor service?

Tags: java, tomcat, executorservice, shutdown

I have a couple of Kafka consumers picking up messages from Kafka clusters, and then they put these messages in an executor service to be processed. The processing of the message itself is time-consuming. When I try to shutdown the application -- that is, shut down Tomcat, what I have noticed is that the executor service will continue to work, but at a much slower pace and with some socket timeout exceptions. That means I can be waiting for a long time for the Tomcat shutdown process to complete but it just keeps running. If I manually kill the Tomcat thread, then I will lose a lot of messages. Is there a way for me to fix this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: Shutdown the executor service in a ContextListener on the shutdown event.

Comment: Probably your Kafka consumer is acknowledging message are received, before they are successfully processed by your application. Either make sure to stop your Kafka consumer on shutdown and process all pending messages; or, do not aknowledge messages until you process them (see the kafka guide..)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Yes I gave it some more thinking last night, and believed that the consumers must be still busy drinking from the hose. Since consumers can pick up messages faster than the messages can be processed by executor, Tomcat has to keep waiting... So we can try to shut down consumers first, and then once that shutdown is confirmed, we can shut down Tomcat. Using Spring Boot, I just started looking for a way to stop the listener. Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062346/how-to-stop-micro-service-with-spring-kafka-listener-when-connection-to-apache.

Answer (score 0):

## Thread pool lives on

The thread pool of an executor may continue running after its parent app has ended. So you should always do a graceful shutdown of the executor when exiting the app.

## `ServletContextListener`

In the case of a web app based on [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology, the [Servlet spec](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/) defines a hook for your web app launching and quitting.

That hook is the [`ServletContextListener`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface. That interface requires a pair of methods, one to be invoked by the Servlet container before the first incoming request to your web app is handled, and another method invoked after the last response has been sent out. Every Servlet container such as Tomcat is required by the spec to invoke these methods at the appropriate times.

In those two methods are the place for you to instantiate your executor service, and then shut it down.

You implement the interface by writing a class. You must also flag that class to the container. The easiest way to flag it is with the [`@WebListener`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html?is-external=true) annotation.

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So [search for more info](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20ServletContextListener&t=hm&ia=web) and examples.

## JSR 236: Concurrency Utilities for Java<sup>TM</sup> EE

This work is much easier if using a full-blown [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/) (formerly [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition)) implementation (Glassfish, Payara, JBoss, etc.) rather than a mere Servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). Such a server will provide an implementation of [JSR 236](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236) to automatically handle the life-cycle of an executor. So no need for you to implement a `ServletContextListener`.

This too has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. So search for more info.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Does the thread pool live on as long as there are tasks to be processed? In my load testing, it looks that the parent app is not shutting down, which is good; otherwise I would probably  be seeing a boat load of exceptions if those resources provided in parent app were no longer available. I am thinking about sending a signal to stop consumers first (a rest call, or maybe a config value change in DB), and then shut down Tomcat. Thanks again!